# Remove blur effect on certain controls inside UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have the following code where I am creating UI controls from Code Behind. Please see the IsEnabled method. I want only the user control's background to be blurred but the problem is the text block on top of it is also getting blurred. Here is the entire code. Please help.

```
public class UserControlLiveAnalysisBehaviour : System.Windows.Interactivity.Behavior<UserControl>
    {
        private UserControl CustomControlContent;

        private bool IsExecuted;
        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            AssociatedObject.Loaded += UserControlLoadedHandler;
        }


        private void UserControlLoadedHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            RegisterUserControlActivatedHandler();
        }

        private void RegisterUserControlActivatedHandler()
        {
            CustomControlContent = AssociatedObject;
            if (CustomControlContent == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            var RunDataInstance = RunDataViewModel.Instance;
            RunDataViewModel.RunDataFileSession<string> session = RunDataInstance.GetLiveSessionObject();
            if (session != null)
            {
                if (session.IsLiveAnalysisSession)
                {
                    IsEnabled();
                }
            }
        }

        private void IsEnabled()
        {
            if (!IsExecuted)
            {
                StackPanel stackPanel = new StackPanel();
                ContentControl cc = new ContentControl();
                StackPanel Sp = new StackPanel();
                Sp.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
                Sp.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
                TextBlock tbl = new TextBlock();
                tbl.Text = "Live Analysis is running. Please wait till it completes....";
                tbl.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
                tbl.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
                Panel.SetZIndex(tbl, 1000);
                //tbl.Style = TextBlockStyle();
                Sp.Children.Add(tbl);
                Sp.Background = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Transparent;
                BlurEffect effect = new BlurEffect();
                effect.Radius = 3;
                CustomControlContent.Effect = effect;
                Sp.Effect = null;
                cc.Content = CustomControlContent.Content;
                stackPanel.Children.Add(cc);
                stackPanel.Children.Add(Sp);
                CustomControlContent.Content = stackPanel;
                IsExecuted = true;
            }
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You apply `effect` to `CustomControlContent` and put everything else inside of it, so the Effect affects everything inside of it. If you want certain elements to be unaffected by this, you can't add them as children of the control that has the Effect applied.

Instead of creating all that in code behind, a simple Style might be easier to maintain and change for this purpose:

```
<ContentControl Name="CustomControlContent" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch">
    <ContentControl.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContentControl">
                                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                                    <ContentPresenter 
                                    Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                    ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                    Cursor="{TemplateBinding Cursor}"
                                    Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                    VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                    Opacity="0.6">
                                        <ContentPresenter.Effect>
                                            <BlurEffect Radius="5"/>
                                        </ContentPresenter.Effect>
                                    </ContentPresenter>
                                    <TextBlock Text="Update, please wait ..." HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ContentControl.Style>
    <ContentControl.Content>
        <Image Source="C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Jellyfish.jpg"/>
    </ContentControl.Content>
</ContentControl>
```

Result:
<sub>Note: I've also reduced the Opacity, that's why the image gets brighter</sub>

[image: Jellyfish]